# How to parameterize the number of parameters of a constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor

I want to accept up to a number of parameters (this number being defined in a template parameter) in a template class constructor.  I can't use an `initializer_list`, since I can't assert its size at compile time, as far as I know.

#### What I tried

My first attempt was using a std::array as a parameter:

```
template<size_t s>
class foo {
  int v[s];
public:
  foo(std::array<int, s>) {/*...*/}
};
```

However, that forces me to initialize like this (even when the constructor is not `explicit`) :

```
foo<4> a{{1,2,3,4}} // Two brackets.
```

I would think there may be some template magic (variadic templates?), but I can't even figure out the proper syntax to use in the constructor. I can't call a constructor recursively... can I?

I tried looking for a definition of the constructor for `std::array`(since it doesn't allow for more parameters than the size of the array, just what I want), but all I could find is that it has implicit constructors. Is that the default constructors? If so, how does

```
std::array<int, 3> a = {1,2,3}
```

work?

Optional bonus: Why didn't the standard define a fixed size alternative to `std::initializer_list`? Something like `std::static_initializer_list<T, N>`. Are there any plans on supporting this kind of functionality in the future? Is it even needed?

Comment: For clarification, you meant to write `std::array<int, s>`, right? I can't find the `n` you got anywhere. Also `std::array` makes use of [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Comment: You got me in the minute I edited to fix it :) Thanks for the link!

Comment: how about using a vector?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want the size as the first argument? Or do you want it automatically handled for you? If you do, use `std::vector` and it's size function, I suppose.

Comment: What do you plan to do when there are fewer arguments than the limit? I am wondering whether a single constructor with default arguments would suffice.

Comment: @liran63 @VermillionAzure I can't assert a `std::vector` size at compile time. I also don't need automatic resizing (quite the contrary: I need my constructor to prevent -at compile time- the user from initializing with more values than the template instance can handle)

Comment: @JonChesterfield In my real use-case scenario, I can infer them, when not present. I can not, however, allow for data loss when the object can't hande all parameters. It wouldn't suffice because I'll only know the number of parameters on template instantiation. (It may be 5, it may be 20)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a variadic constructor and just assert that it was provided the right number of arguments:

```
template <size_t SZ>
struct Foo {
    template <typename... Args>
    Foo(Args... args) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) <= SZ, "Invalid number of arguments");
        // ... stuff ...
    }
};
```

So that:

```
Foo<3> f;                // OK
Foo<3> f(1, 2, 3);       // OK
Foo<3> f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // error
```

As an example to initialize an array, that could look like:

```
template <size_t SZ>
struct Foo {
    template <typename... Args>
    Foo(Args... args) 
    : v{{args...}}
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) <= SZ, "Invalid number of arguments");
    }

    std::array<int, SZ> v;
};
```

That constructs `v` correctly as you'd expect, though if you try to pass more than `SZ` args to `Foo`'s constructor, you'd see the error on initializing `v` before the `static_assert`.

For a clearer `static_assert` error, you could delegate the top-level `Foo` to private constructors that take an extra `integral_constant` argument for whether or not they're valid constructors:

```
template <typename... Args>
Foo(Args... args)
: Foo(std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof...(Args) <= SZ>{}, 
      args...)
{ }

private:
template <typename... Args>
Foo(std::true_type, Args... args)
: v{{args...}}
{ }

template <typename False, typename... Args>
Foo(False, Args... )
{ 
    // False is only ever std::false_type
    static_assert(False::value, "Invalid number of arguments!");
}
```

Comment: How would you "get" the parameters though?

Comment: I read the OP's statement "*... **up to** a number of parameters ...*" as meaning the OP wants to accept a *variable* number of parameters but not to exceed a max number.  In that case, I think the `static_assert` would have to use `<=` instead of `==`.

Comment: @vsoftco I thought you don't have to get them? You just `(Args...)` and things should be good when you substitute, provided you have the correct constructor waiting, right?

Comment: @VermillionAzure I guess it depends on the situation. Say that you want to initialize the array `v` in OPs code with the parameters of the constructor. How would you do this without some kind of recursion/pattern matching on the `Args...` type passing?

Comment: @vsoftco Make it a `std::array<int, SZ> v` instead, and then just `v({{args...}})` works just fine.

Comment: Since `v` is an aggregate you could just do `v{{x...}}` or `v{x...}` if your compiler supports brace-elision. Moreover, I don't see the point in the `static_assert` since if there are more elements than allotted then `std::array` will issue a compiler error before the constructor body is even called.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That's true. I could do things like delegate to `Foo(true_type, args...)` if it's an allowed number or `Foo(false_type, args...)` if it's not, and have the latter `static_assert`. That'd give you a cleaner error?

Comment: You also might want to make the condition to the assertion dependent to avoid premature instantiation.